# AJAX - Function is called for every uploaded file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using [jquery-html5-uploader](http://www.igloolab.com/jquery-html5-uploader/) to upload files via AJAX, and I have following problem. When the file is uploaded, the**handleSuccess** function is being called - for every uploaded file. That is creating me a problem - when you click on image link is being inserted in textarea. In my case, for every file, the same number of links are being inserted. How can I call function only once, or remove all objects created and get only one object (or basically anything that can prevent this )?
Code:

```
function img_upload(url) {
    {
        var fileTemplate = "<div role=\"id_image\"  id=\"{{id}}\" class=\"clearfix fl slika_prv\" >";
        fileTemplate += "<div class=\"preview\"></div>";
        fileTemplate += "<div class=\"filename\">{{filename}}</div>";
        fileTemplate += "<a href=\"" + url_tmp_delete  + "\"  class=\"image_delete_tmp\" role={{id}}>Obriši Sliku</a>";
        fileTemplate += "</div>";

        function slugify(text) {
            text = text.replace(/[^-a-zA-Z0-9,&\s]+/ig, '');
            text = text.replace(/-/gi, "_");
            text = text.replace(/\s/gi, "-");
            return text;
        }
        $("#dropbox").html5Uploader({
            postUrl: url,
            onClientLoadStart: function (e, file) {
                var upload = $("#upload");
                if (upload.is(":hidden")) {
                    upload.show();
                }
                upload.append(fileTemplate.replace(/{{id}}/g, slugify(file.name)).replace(/{{filename}}/g, file.name))
            },
            onClientLoad: function (e, file) {
                $("#" + slugify(file.name))
                    .find(".preview")
                    .append("<img class=img_upload title=\"" + file.name + "\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" alt=\"\">");

            },
            onServerLoad: function (e, file) {

            },
            onSuccess : function(e, file, data) {
            var id_slika = slugify(file.name)
            upload_folder = $('#upload');
            upload_folder.find('#' + id_slika).find('a').attr('data-id', data);

                var img_delete = $('.image_delete_tmp');
            handleSuccess(upload_folder);

                delete_image(img_delete, 'tmp');
            }
        });
    }
}

function handleSuccess() {
  var upload_folder = $('#upload');
  console.log(upload_folder.first());
  upload_folder.on('click', 'img', function(e){

    var $this = $(this),
    text = $this.parent().parent().find('a').data('id'),
    img = ('<img src="<?php echo IMG ?>pages/' +  text +  '" />');
    $("#page_srb").insertAtCursor(img);
    // element.remove();
    return false;

});
}
```

And this is what I get when I click on file (this is for 3 files):

```
<img src="http://localhost/pirot_opstina/public/img/pages/Digital_composite_spring_(9)37.jpg" />
    <img src="http://localhost/pirot_opstina/public/img/pages/Digital_composite_spring_(9)37.jpg" />
    <img src="http://localhost/pirot_opstina/public/img/pages/Digital_composite_spring_(9)37.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

it would be easy if this plugin supported something like onSuccessAll... but it doesn't by the look of it... if it's only the matter of displaying only one image, I would:

```
function handleSuccess() {
  var upload_folder = $('#upload');
  console.log(upload_folder.first());
  upload_folder.on('click', 'img', function(e){

    if ($(".onlyone").length < 1){
        var $this = $(this),
        text = $this.parent().parent().find('a').data('id'),
        img = ('<img class="onlyone" src="<?php echo IMG ?>pages/' +  text +  '" />');
        $("#page_srb").insertAtCursor(img);
        // element.remove();
        return false;
    }
});
}
```

so it checks if there are already elements with class `onlyone` and only if there isn't it will add image. However it means that image will be displayed from the first upload, not the last.

Comment: I am still getting the same result. I guess I will have to find the way to insert onSuccessAll functionality.

Comment: that is strange... did you definitely overridden your original function?.... anyway i'm myself using http://www.uploadify.com/ for the same purpose. very easy to use and customise..